# From in-order representation to binary tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, binary-trees

Is there a way to reconstruct a binary tree just from its in-order representation?

I've searched the internet, but I could only find solutions for reconstructing a binary tree from inorder and preorder representations, but none for only inorder.

Comment: See also [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/439/which-combinations-of-pre-post-and-in-order-sequentialisation-are-unique) (which doesn't explain why in-order isn't enough on its own).

Answer (score 6):

[image: **Example Trees**]

The in-order traversal is not unique. The above trees have the same sequence 1,2,3,4,5. (They are isomorphic, but I assumed you consider ordered binary trees.)