# How to identify a binary tree uniquely if its Inorder, Preorder and Postorder traversal is given?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which combinations of pre-, post- and in-order sequentialisation are unique?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/439/which-combinations-of-pre-post-and-in-order-sequentialisation-are-unique)

I have three different tree traversal of a binary tree Inorder, Preorder and Postorder. I want to identify the tree back from these traversal. I found that a single traversal cant not identify the tree.
 So if I'll take in pair then can I identiy the tree?

Comment: You can find an answer [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/439/which-combinations-of-pre-post-and-in-order-sequentialisation-are-unique).